# Error parsing data to JSON

Tags: android, json

Why i get this error when running my android app. The login is successful but in the logcat it show this error : E/JSON Parser: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value Table of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject. I import this project from my friend and i'm new to android and JSON

Here is my JSON parsing code:

```
public class JSONParser {

  static InputStream is = null;
  static JSONObject jObj = null;
  static String json = "";

  // constructor
  public JSONParser() {

  }

  // function get json from url
  // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
  public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method.equals("POST")){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method.equals("GET")){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
           // String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
           //url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           


    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;
  }
}
```

Comment: Need more info like response string.

Comment: what does it means? where can i get the response string

Comment: The problem is your response String is not valid for creating `JSON`

Comment: Where is the stacktrace?

Comment: @nur what response string you are getting as sb.toString()

Comment: @AbuYousuf: how can i correct the code?

Comment: @nur Please debug your app using add breakpoints and then find what is the result you are getting in json

Comment: @nur Error in  jObj = new JSONObject(json); this line, because i think response of json is not in JsonObject type it is may be JsonArray or string type

Comment: @nur post your response string

Comment: @AbuYousuf: how can i get the response string?

Comment: @nur make a Server call using postman and check the response, that in which type response comes is it string or JsonArray or JsonObject. so after that, you know which type of response you get into a server call.